# Parsing Retrofit2 result using Gson with different JSON structures

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

When I call the API, depending on the parameters, the name of the same field in the JSON returned changes. In the example below, in one case the field "user" is named "userA" or "userB".
I'm using Gson but I don't want to create an object to parse the root of the JSON as I'm only interested in the list of users and I want my call to return this list only.

```
{
    "apiVersion":"42"
    "usersA":[{
        "name":"Foo",
        "lastname":"Bar"
        ...
    }
    ]
    "otherData":"..."
}
```

or

```
{
    "apiVersion":"42"
    "usersB":[{
        "name":"Foo",
        "lastname":"Bar"
        ...
    }
    ]
    "otherData":"..."
}
```

I know that I could use a TypeAdapter but I want to use the same Retrofit client to do different calls and the JSON structure can be very different depending on the API end point.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know **all possible names** of this 'user' field? If so, you **can** use `alternate` param in `@SerializedName`. If you don't know them, but know other fields, I suggest you to use `TypeAdapter` for this API call.

But I really don't understand, why you think, that `TypeAdapter` makes you change your `Retrofit` client.

Comment: No I don't know all possible names.
I'm not quite sure how to implement the adapter. As I said I only want to get the list of users from the response so I'd like to prevent the creation of  unecessary classes like a "ResponseAPI" containing the "apiVersion" and all the rest that is not necessary.

Comment: You should always avoid placing personal information within an application's code or packed files. Placing any possible names in @SerializedName would yield a very bad app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that I could use a TypeAdapter but I want to use the same Retrofit client to do different calls and the JSON structure can be very different depending on the API end point.

Well, you can do it, and it's even easier with Retrofit 2 rather than plain Gson.

For example

```java
final class User {

    final String name = null;
    final String lastname = null;

}
```

```java
interface IService {

    @GET("/")
    @Unwrap
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();

}
```

Note the `@Unwrap` annotation above. This is an optional custom annotation marking that the call response body should be "unwrapped":

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@interface Unwrap {
}
```

Now you can just create a Retrofit converter factory that would analyze the annotation. Of course, this cannot cover all the cases, but it's extensible and you can improve it:

```java
final class UnwrappingGsonConverterFactory
        extends Converter.Factory {

    private final Gson gson;

    private UnwrappingGsonConverterFactory(final Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    static Converter.Factory create(final Gson gson) {
        return new UnwrappingGsonConverterFactory(gson);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
        if ( !needsUnwrapping(annotations) ) {
            return super.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        }
        final TypeAdapter<?> typeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
        return new UnwrappingResponseConverter(typeAdapter);
    }

    private static boolean needsUnwrapping(final Annotation[] annotations) {
        for ( final Annotation annotation : annotations ) {
            if ( annotation instanceof Unwrap ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static final class UnwrappingResponseConverter
            implements Converter<ResponseBody, Object> {

        private final TypeAdapter<?> typeAdapter;

        private UnwrappingResponseConverter(final TypeAdapter<?> typeAdapter) {
            this.typeAdapter = typeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public Object convert(final ResponseBody responseBody)
                throws IOException {
            try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(responseBody.charStream()) ) {
                // Checking if the JSON document current value is null
                final JsonToken token = jsonReader.peek();
                if ( token == JsonToken.NULL ) {
                    return null;
                }
                // If it's an object, expect `{`
                jsonReader.beginObject();
                Object value = null;
                // And iterate over all properties
                while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                    final String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                    // I'm assuming apiVersion and otherData should be skipped
                    switch ( name ) {
                    case "apiVersion":
                    case "otherData":
                        jsonReader.skipValue();
                        break;
                    // But any other is supposed to contain the required value (or null)
                    default:
                        value = typeAdapter.read(jsonReader);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Consume the object end `}`
                jsonReader.endObject();
                return value;
            } finally {
                responseBody.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I've tested it with the following code:

```java
for ( final String filename : ImmutableList.of("usersA.json", "usersB.json") ) {
    // Mocking the HTTP client to return a JSON document always
    final OkHttpClient client = new Builder()
            .addInterceptor(staticResponse(Q43921751.class, filename))
            .build();
    // Note the order of converter factories
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://whatever")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(UnwrappingGsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    final IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);
    service.getUsers()
            .execute()
            .body()
            .forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.name + " " + user.lastname));
}
```

Output:

> Foo Bar
>   Foo Bar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a very stupid answer, but if u need only names/last names and don't want to deal with TypeAdapter for some reason AND you don't care about speed, you can ...  
just go through the response body and using String Utils just scrape names and create a list.add(new User(String first, String last)) 
Kinda...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create special `ResponseApi` class with different fields for your purposes. You can just create `TypeAdapter` targeted for `List<User>` class.
Like this:

1. Create `TypeAdapter` class, e.g.

   ```
   public class GsonUsersDeserializer extends TypeAdapter<List<User>> {

       @Override
       public void write(JsonWriter out, List<User> value) throws IOException {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
       }

       @Override
       public List<User> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
           List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
           in.beginObject();

           while (in.hasNext()) {
               switch (in.nextName()) {
                   case "usersA":
                   case "usersB":
                       // Try to read all users
                       in.beginArray();
                       while (in.hasNext()) {
                           users.add(readUser(in));
                       }
                       in.endArray();
                       break;

                  default:
                      // Just skip all other data in deserializer
                      in.skipValue();
                      break;
               }
           }

           in.endObject();
           return users;
       }

       private User readUser(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
           User user = new User();

           in.beginObject();
           while (in.hasNext()) {
               switch (in.nextName()) {
                   case "name":
                       user.setName(in.nextString());
                       break;

                   // ...

                   default:
                       in.skipValue();
                       break;
               }
           }
           in.endObject();

           return user;
       }

   }
   ```
2. When you create your `Retrofit` client:

   ```
   Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClien) {
       // Create type targeted for list of users.
       Type userListType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();

       // Create Gson object for converter factory
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                       .registerTypeAdapter(userListType, new GsonUsersDeserializer())
                       .create();

       // Create Retrofit object
       return new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(Config.BASE_SERVER_URL)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson ))
           .client(okHttpClient)
           .build();
   }
   ```
3. And in your API interface:

   ```
   public interface MyApi {

       @GET("myUsersApiCall")
       Call<List<User>> getUsers();

   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `alternate` parameter in `SerializedName` annotation, like this:

```
@SerializedName(value="usersA", alternate={"usersB"}) User user;
```

More details are [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

Comment: Yes I could but I can't predict the field's name

Comment: Placing personal data into code is not the right way to do this.